# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'- unable to understand this ( i tried float() function also

Tags: ipython, ipython-magic

I am unable to calculate another columns by diving or multiplying 
through below code-

```
csv_data["male Turnout"]=csv_data["Male Voters"]/csv_data["Male Electors"]
```

> male turnout- New column name male voters- existing column male
>   electors- existing column

i am unable to understand how to convert str to int as it shows -

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' when ever i execute
>   code--

i also tried

```
mydata=float(csv_data())
```

to convert csv_data- my dataset name

Comment: `csv_data["male Turnout"]=float(csv_data["Male Voters"])/float(csv_data["Male Electors"])`

Comment: i got below error when i executed your code         -cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Comment: please turn this into a [mcve] then.

Comment: tried a lot  but still i am unable to solve the issue as  i am very new to ipython . below is my table                       want to convert to float               State PC Name Male Electors Male Voters Male Turnout Female Electors Female Voters Female Turnout Total Electors Total Voters Total Turnout
Andaman Andaman 1,42,782 1,01,178 70.86% 1,26,578 89,150 70.43% 2,69,360 1,90,328 70.66%
Andhra Pradesh Adilabad 6,87,389 5,19,364 75.56% 6,98,844 5,26,475 75.34% 13,86,233 10,45,839 75.44%
Andhra Pradesh Peddapalle 7,25,767 5,20,598 71.73% 6,99,594 5,01,586 71.70% 14,25,361 10,22,184 71.71%